# Getting a summary report based on grouping 2 user IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as such:

```
MsgID   MsgrUserID  MsgdUserID  MsgDate     Message 
1          1            4       6/12/2015   Jules - Did you pick up the blueprints?
2          4            1       6/15/2015   Yes, they're in my hands
3          4            1       6/15/2015   Let me know when you can talk
4          3            4       6/16/2015   Jules, let's meet tomorrow
5          1            4       6/17/2015   I'm available at 2 PM today
6          1            3       7/4/2015    Cindy, did you check your mail?
7          4            3       7/3/2015    OK, I'm free after 3PM
8          3            1       7/2/2015    Yes, there was nothing there
9          2            1       7/5/2015    Plan is going well.  Just need more time
10         1            2       7/5/2015    OK, great.  Let me know
```

What I need to do is get a report that sums up all of the correspondence.  It would look something like this:

```
User: 1
    Correspondence between you and 2: 2      Last correspondence: 7/5/2015
    Correspondence between you and 3: 2      Last correspondence: 7/4/2015
    Correspondence between you and 4: 4      Last correspondence: 6/17/2015
```

Or something like that.  So, I need to figure out how to sum the number of correspondence, but also get other pieces of information from the original table.  The problem I'm having is that I can't figure out how to link the sum to the original table, because it's conditional.  Sometimes the user's ID is in the Msgr (Messenger) field, and sometimes it's in the Msgd (Messaged) field.

I've got this monster, but I know the join to #MyMsgs table is where the error lies.

```
with cte as (
    select 
    MessagedUserID as MessagedUserIDOrig,
    MessagerUserID as MessagerUserIDOrig,
       case when MessagerUserID < MessagedUserID 
            then MessagerUserID else MessagedUserID end MessagerUserID, 
       case when MessagerUserID > MessagedUserID 
            then MessagerUserID else MessagedUserID end MessagedUserID
    from tmpMessaged
)

select MessagerUserID, MessagedUserID, count(*) as Contact 
into #MyMsgs
from cte 
WHERE MessagerUserID = @MyID
    OR MessagedUserID = @MyID
group by MessagerUserID, MessagedUserID


SELECT 
    T1.*, 
    Mgr.UserName as MessagerName, 
    Mgr.UserID as UserID, 
    CASE WHEN T1.MessagedUserID = @MyID THEN Mgd.UserImg1 ELSE Mgr.UserImg1 END as UserImg1, 
    Mgd.UserName as MessagedName,
    CC.Contact,
    Mgd.LastLoginDate as LastOnline,
    CASE WHEN T1.MessagedUserID = @MyID THEN 'Received' ELSE 'Sent' END as LContact,
    LEFT(T1.[Message], 100) + '...' as [uMessage],
    CASE WHEN T1.MessageViewed IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END as MsgViewed,
    CASE WHEN T1.MessageFlag IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END as MsgFlagged
FROM [dbo].[tmpMessaged] T1
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tmpUsers] Mgr
ON T1.[MessagerUserID] = Mgr.[UserID]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tmpUsers] Mgd
ON T1.[MessagedUserID] = Mgd.[UserID]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tmpMessaged] T2
  ON T1.MessageID = T2.MessageID
    LEFT JOIN #MyMsgs CC 
        ON CASE 
      --     WHEN T1.MessagerUserID = @MyID AND CC.MessagerUserID = T1.MessagerUserID THEN 1
           WHEN T1.MessagedUserID = @MyID AND CC.MessagedUserID = T1.MessagedUserID THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END = 1


WHERE
    -- First grab the records where the User's ID is in the Messaged field
    Mgd.[UserID] = @MyID

UNION

SELECT 
    T1.*, 
    Mgr.UserName as MessagerName, 
    Mgr.UserID as UserID, 
    CASE WHEN T1.MessagerUserID = @MyID THEN Mgr.UserImg1 ELSE Mgd.UserImg1 END as UserImg1, 
    Mgd.UserName as MessagedName,
    CC.Contact,
    Mgd.LastLoginDate as LastOnline,
    CASE WHEN T1.MessagerUserID = @MyID THEN 'Sent' ELSE 'Received' END as LContact,
    LEFT(T1.[Message], 100) + '...' as [uMessage],
    CASE WHEN T1.MessageViewed IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END as MsgViewed,
    CASE WHEN T1.MessageFlag IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END as MsgFlagged
FROM [dbo].[tmpMessaged] T1
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tmpUsers] Mgr
ON T1.[MessagerUserID] = Mgr.[UserID]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tmpUsers] Mgd
ON T1.[MessagedUserID] = Mgd.[UserID]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tmpMessaged] T2
  ON T1.MessageID = T2.MessageID
    LEFT JOIN #MyMsgs CC 
        ON CASE 
           WHEN T1.MessagerUserID = @MyID AND CC.MessagerUserID = T1.MessagerUserID THEN 1
      --     WHEN T1.MessagedUserID = @MyID AND CC.MessagerUserID = T1.MessagedUserID THEN 1
           ELSE 0
           END = 1

WHERE
    -- Now grab the records where the User's ID is in the Messager field
    Mgr.[UserID] = @MyID

ORDER BY T1.MessageDate DESC
```

Comment: Do you ever have a scenario where a user messages himself?  i.e. MsgrUserID = MsgdUserID on a record?

Comment: No, that won't ever happen.

Comment: Some friendly advice: people might be more inclined to help you if you acknowledge the help you get. Just saying since I see you incorporated code from the my answer to your last question here and that remains open.

Answer (score 2):

You could just do the aggregation directly in the common table expression:

```
declare @myID int = 1;

with cte as (
    select 
       case when MessagerUserID < MessagedUserID 
            then MessagerUserID else MessagedUserID end MessagerUserID, 
       case when MessagerUserID > MessagedUserID 
            then MessagerUserID else MessagedUserID end MessagedUserID,
       count(*) MessageCount,
       max(MessageDate) LastMessageDate    
    from tmpMessaged
    group by 
       case when MessagerUserID < MessagedUserID 
            then MessagerUserID else MessagedUserID end,
       case when MessagerUserID > MessagedUserID 
            then MessagerUserID else MessagedUserID end
)

select * from cte where MessagerUserID = @myID;
```

With your sample data this would result in:

```
MessagerUserID MessagedUserID MessageCount LastMessageDate    
-------------- -------------- ------------ ---------------
1              2              2            2015-07-05
1              3              2            2015-07-04
1              4              4            2015-06-17
```

The specific formatting with headers/details etc is probably better to do in the actual reporting application, although it's certainly possibly to do directly on the server too (but who uses SSMS for pretty reports anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I asked about the sender ever being the receiver and got the answer I hoped for (no).  With that rule in place, you can "cheat" and double-stack the records, swapping participant 1 and participant 2 in half of them, then only concern yourself with selecting from that structure and treating participant 1 as "your guy" and participant 2 as "other guy".  You'll never double-count a record when sender cannot ever equal receiver.

```
DECLARE @UserYouCareAbout int

SET @UserYouCareAbout = 1

SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(max), GETDATE(), 101)

SELECT
    'Correspondence between you and ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), [Message Participant 2]) + ': ' + STR(MAX(MsgDate), 4, 0) AS [Conversation With],
    'Last correspondence: ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max), MAX(MsgDate), 101) AS [Last Communication]
    /*
    --individual unformatted pieces
    ,
    COUNT(MsgID) AS [MessageCount],
    [Message Participant 2] AS [Other Guy],
    MAX(MsgDate) AS [LastDate]
    */
FROM
    (
        (
        SELECT
            MsgID, 
            MsgrUserID AS [Message Participant 1],
            MsgdUserID AS [Message Participant 2],
            MsgDate
        FROM
            tmpMessaged
        ) --SentStuff
        UNION ALL
        (
        SELECT
            MsgID, 
            MsgdUserID AS [Message Participant 1], --note that
            MsgrUserID AS [Message Participant 2], --these switched
            MsgDate
        FROM
            tmpMessaged
        ) --RecStuff
    ) DerivedAllMessagesTwice
WHERE
    [Message Participant 1] = @UserYouCareAbout
GROUP BY
    [Message Participant 2]
```

This simplification eliminates all of the inline conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :-

```
declare @MyID int = 1
create table #yourmsgtable (MsgID  int,  MsgrUserID  int, MsgdUserID  int, MsgDate     date, Message varchar(max))
insert into #yourmsgtable values
(1,1,4,'6/12/2015','Jules - Did you pick up the blueprints?'),
(2,4,1,'6/15/2015','Yes, they''re in my hands'),
(3,4,1,'6/15/2015','Let me know when you can talk'),
(4,3,4,'6/16/2015','Jules, let''s meet tomorrow'),
(5,1,4,'6/17/2015','I''m available at 2 PM today'),
(6,1,3,'7/4/2015','Cindy, did you check your mail?'),
(7,4,3,'7/3/2015','OK, I''m free after 3PM'),
(8,3,1,'7/2/2015','Yes, there was nothing there'),
(9,2,1,'7/5/2015','Plan is going well.  Just need more time'),
(10,1,2,'7/5/2015','OK, great.  Let me know')
create table #tmpmsgtable(party1 int, party2 int, msgdate date)

insert into #tmpmsgtable
select MsgrUserID, MsgdUserID, MsgDate from #yourmsgtable where MsgrUserID = @MyID
union all
select MsgdUserID, MsgrUserID, MsgDate from #yourmsgtable where MsgdUserID = @MyID

select
'User : ' + convert(varchar(max),party1) 'Party 1', 
'Correspondence between you and ' + convert(varchar(max),party2) + ' : ' + convert(varchar(max),count(*)) 'Party 2 Correspondence', 
'Last correspondence : ' + convert(nvarchar(max),max(msgdate)) 'Last correspondence'
from #tmpmsgtable
group by party1, party2

drop table #tmpmsgtable
drop table #yourmsgtable
```

Result :-

[image]